# What is the difference between ‘The meeting is/has finished’ and "meeting over" or "meeting done"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrases, questions, spoken-english

What is the difference between ‘The meeting is/has finished’ and "meeting over" or "meeting done" and can use like "meeting completed"?

Could anyone please advise which is more natural and when should one use over the other with sentences?

Comment: Same meaning of above 3 sentences but expression are not same when they are said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean  that the meeting is at an end, you can use over, finished, ended, done, or completed as an adjective. For example: The meeting is over/finished/ended/done/completed.

You can also use finished and ended in the present perfect tense. For example: The meeting has finished/ended.

However, the use of the over as an adjective is the most common in this context.

The meeting is over.

Answer (score 0):

*The meeting has finished* is a proper sentence. *The meeting is over* and *The meeting has been completed* are also sentences.

*Meeting over* etc. are just phrases, which you might use in making notes or to signify that an online meeting is over, but not in correct speech or writing.